# ggplot: change the order of stacked bars based on the a name within the bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=ab,y=Freq/total,fill=Result))+
      geom_bar(stat="identity")+
     theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size=8, angle=0),
      strip.background = element_rect(colour="black", fill="#CCCCFF"))+
    ggtitle("H.somnus SIR %")+ylab("% SIR")+
    scale_y_continuous(labels=percent,breaks=seq(0,1,.1))+
    theme_set(theme_barplot())
```

Above is the code that I am using.   data is a table that I have melted, but the column 'result' is in an order that is alphabetical and the str(result) is a factor with 4 levels: like A,B,C,D.  What I would like to display the bars with the largest bar on the bottom and the order would be D,B,C,A

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a hacked fix but it works. ggplot will plot the stacked bars in the order it encounters them when using stat = "identity". To get the stack in the order D,B,C,A reorder your data.frame like this:

```
data <- data[c(data$Result == "D",
               data$Result == "B",
               data$Result == "C",
               data$Result == "A"),]
```

the entry in the [ggplot2](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html) help files could be better in this respect.