# Changing the Order of Levels through ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to learn the package `cregg` through the tutorial [here](https://thomasleeper.com/cregg/reference/plot.html). The tutorial works fine. However, I have an issue when I try to change the default setting of the functions. It looks like when it plots, the order of the levels and coef dots of the legend is ordered alphabetically or by numbers. My question is that when I have tried two ways: one if through the ggplot function and the second one is to change the order of levels in advance to change the order to, say `31524`, both methods do not work. The original codes are as follow:

```
data("immigration")
stacked <- cj(immigration, ChosenImmigrant ~ Gender +
          Education + LanguageSkills + CountryOfOrigin + Job + JobExperience +
          JobPlans + ReasonForApplication + PriorEntry, id = ~ CaseID,
          estimate = "mm", by = ~ contest_no)
plot(stacked, group = "contest_no", feature_headers = FALSE)
```

My question is how I can the order of levels of `contest_no` both on the plot and in the legend. One thing I have found is that it seems like the order of levels of `contest_no` is determined by the function `cj` first (you can check it by `stacked[["contest_no"]]`). Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot: change the order of stacked bars based on the a name within the bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913106/ggplot-change-the-order-of-stacked-bars-based-on-the-a-name-within-the-bar)

Comment: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html

Comment: Thanks to @Tung! I think I figure out the answer. In my question I kind of having the answer but I didn't know why I didn't see it. Since `stacked[["contest_no"]]` can show the order of levels of `stacked[["contest_no"]]`, I just change the order by `stacked[["contest_no"]] <- factor(stacked[["contest_no"]], levels=c(3, 1, 5, 2, 4))` and then plot the whole object of `stacked`. It works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Tung!(I know I left a similar comment but I still want to answer this one and close it) The answer is simple and straightforward but I didn't think it completely. In my question I kind of having the answer but I didn't know why I didn't see it. Since `stacked[["contest_no"]]` can show the order of levels of `stacked[["contest_no"]]`, I just change the order by `stacked[["contest_no"]] <- factor(stacked[["contest_no"]], levels=c(3, 1, 5, 2, 4))` and then plot the whole object of `stacked`. It works fine.